How to not lose the feeling of the meter?
I’m learning how to improvise on the piano and I am running into trouble maintaining the “feel” of the meter as I improvise rhythm.
For example, if I play a drone note on the first beat of every two measures with my left hand and play phrases with my right hand, unless I know the rhythm of the phrase I’m playing very well I will not know what beat it ends on and will not be able to play the next “one” with my left. The implication is that I cannot improvise rhythm because I lose the feeling of the meter and it throws off my left hand.
Things I tried that don’t seem to help:

Practicing increasingly complex rhythm patterns with two hands: i just memorize the sound / coordination of the specific pattern.
Any kind of reading exercise: gives me a visual indication of which beat I am on.
Working with a metronome: I seem to do ok when I have an external pulse to orient myself against.
If I try to count the beats out loud I completely lose the ability to improvise on my right.

What are some good exercises to help me maintain a good internal feeling of meter even when I’m focusing on other musical aspects?
Edit: the improv exercise I’m doing is using the phrase below from a piece I learned several months ago as material (varying the pitches / contour/ rhythm over a drone bass note).

Thanks!

Do you normally play music of similar rhythmic complexity, that is not improvised? E.g. classical music compositions, written down jazz arrangements, etc?

Yes, specifically today I tried to borrow a phrase from a familiar piece I worked on several months ago and use it as material for improvisation. As long as I vary the pitches / contour I’m good, when I start playing with the rhythm I lose the meter.

Don't use a metronome, use a drum machine, or better still, find others to play with.

Take a look at How can you listen and judge where you are in the music whilst improvising? and Why do i keep forgeting the sections while improvising?.


Practicing increasingly complex rhythm patterns with two hands: i just memorize the sound / coordination of the specific pattern.

As a drummer myself, I've always held the theory that "independence" is largely a bit of an illusion.  A drummer isn't truly playing 3 or 4 different musical ideas at once, rather they've learned all the different ways the hands and feet can fit together.  There are few enough rhythm patterns that you can learn to play every possible combination of 16th notes over 1 or 2 beats between the two hands.  Then do it with triplets.  That gives you a rhythmic vocabulary.  It's not cheating; you don't have to improvise from first principles.

If I try to count the beats out loud I completely lose the ability to improvise on my right.

Then improvise slower or simpler parts.  I think this is a good way to develop your ability to keep track of the downbeat, and you should keep doing this exercise.

Thanks, that’s helpful! I always assumed drummers just maintain internal meter along with whatever rhythmic thinking is going on at the moment.

We do maintain internal meter (at least, the good ones do).  But, the ability to do that while improvising comes from having some rhythmic vocabulary.  Ask a drummer to improvise in 7/8 and many will lose track of the downbeat, or perhaps some will be able to do it, but only while using a small handful of 7/8 rhythms that they have been required to play before.  It's not like counting to 7 is that much harder than counting to 4!  They just don't have the rhythmic vocabulary.

I remember Adam Neely describing each time signature as a "language" where each possible measure of rhythm is a "word," point being that when you switch to an uncommon time signature you have to learn a whole set of new ones. I thought it was a stretch at first, but it's stuck with me.
